# SWT MessageBox doesn't show correct icon

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I'm trying to create an error message with a `MessageBox`:

```
MessageBox b = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.ICON_ERROR);
b.setMessage(text);
b.open();
```

The message box pops up just fine, but has a warning icon instead of an error icon.

I'm using a Mac. Not sure if this makes a difference, but I've played around with a couple other icons and they're all plain, they don't even correspond to their styles.

Anyone else encounter this problem? I haven't found any information on something like this.

Comment: I can only report, that on Windows, the documented `SWT.ICON_` styles look as expected (well, except for the rather odd `WORKING` style).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in SWT on macOS:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=144689

Is that the problem you are seeing?

Judging from the bug's age and the comments it seems not an easy fix and unlikely that this will be resolved soon.

If you are depending on JFace already and you don't mind the non-native look, the [MessageDialog.](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdialogs%2FMessageDialog.html) and its subclasses may help you to work around this issue.

Comment: Ugh, yup, that's it. Wow, that's been a problem forever. I'll try the MessageDialog class and see how that works. Otherwise I suppose I could try to customize the icon. Thanks.

Comment: If you mean to customize the `MessageBox` icon, I think that's not possible. Customizing the JFace `MessageDialog` icon can be done by overriding (shiver) `getErrorImage()` (or Warning/Info/Question). Otherwise the _system images_ (obtained from `display.getSystemimage( SWT.ICON_ )` will be used.